# What is the meaning of this verse from Parashara Smriti?

Tags: smriti, parashara

Chapter 1 verse 32 of [Parashara Smriti](https://archive.org/stream/ParasharaSmriti/SriParasharaSmrithiPdf_djvu.txt) says

> Life in the Krita has its seat in the bones ; in the Treta it has its
>   seat in the flesh ; in the Dvapara the blood is the seat of life ; in
>   the Kali, however, life is dependent upon food and the like

I would like to understand the meaning of this verse. It is understandable that our life depends on food in kaliyuga and we cannot live without food.

But what is meaning of rest of the verse?

Comment: At least this verse helps understanding how people in Krita, Treta yuga were able to perform tapasya for thousands of years (since they could live without food).

Answer (score 1):

This means that the humans in Krita Yuga could remain energetic without food for many years and their energy depends on the bone’s strength and not just on the food that they eat.

The life-span of the humans in the Satya Yuga was one hundred thousand years and each subsequent Yugas the life-span, strength of humans has decreased. Thus, the human bodies produced by the nature was quite different in Satya Yuga from the human bodies produced in Kaliyuga. So we cannot reason it from archaeological evidences or study of the biology.

Comment: It is also said that there was no agriculture in Satya Yuga as the earth was giving abundant of fruits, vegetables, etc. without the need to cultivate the soil. This could mean that the top soil of the earth was so fertile.

Comment: In Puranas, it is said that people used to meditate on God for thousand of years without food even though their skin and the muscles were eaten by ants and bacteria.  But as long as the person's bones are strong, he was probably energetic. This was the biological power of the human bodies in those Yugas. The nature used to produce such bodies in Satya Yuga.